# Google+ sever side sign up on to my application

Tags: php, google-plus

Hey I am getting the authorization code form my localhost page. How to get the access token using this authorization code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest if you use the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
```

Then when you have the authorization code you can call:

```
$client->authenticate($code);
$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
access_token = $token->access_token;
```

You can then use the access token in requests or use the client library to access various Google APIs (which is much easier).

Also see https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php and https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php/ for full examples of the flow.

Comment: hey Scarygami thanks for your answer.I am getting stuck in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276513/how-to-create-an-anti-request-forgery-state-token-in-google-server-side-sign-up/16277569#16277569.Plz give me the help