# How to Create an anti-request forgery state token In google+ server side sign-up

Tags: php, server-side, google-plus, google-oauth

```
    <?php
     require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
     require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

     session_start();
     // Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
     // Store it in the session for later validation.
     $state = md5(rand());
     $app['session']->set('state', $state);
     // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
     // serving it.
     return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
      'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
      'STATE' => $state,
      'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
     ));

      // Ensure that this is no request forgery going on, and that the user
     // sending us this connect request is the user that was supposed to.
    if ($request->get('state') != ($app['session']->get('state'))) {
    return new Response('Invalid state parameter', 401);
   }


    $code = $request->getContent();
    $gPlusId = $request->get['gplus_id'];
    // Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
    $client->authenticate($code);

    $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
    // Verify the token
    $reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' .
          $token->access_token;
    $req = new Google_HttpRequest($reqUrl);

    $tokenInfo = json_decode(
      $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());

     // If there was an error in the token info, abort.
    if ($tokenInfo->error) {
    return new Response($tokenInfo->error, 500);
    }
     // Make sure the token we got is for the intended user.
     if ($tokenInfo->userid != $gPlusId) {
      return new Response(
        "Token's user ID doesn't match given user ID", 401);
     }
    // Make sure the token we got is for our app.
    if ($tokenInfo->audience != CLIENT_ID) {
    return new Response(
        "Token's client ID does not match app's.", 401);
    }

    // Store the token in the session for later use.
    $app['session']->set('token', json_encode($token));
    $response = 'Succesfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);
   ?>
```

This is my code.php.
I have taken this code from https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow.
I want to add google+ server side sign-up in to my application. 
so i decide to run the sample code. 
I am getting the error while i have run the code.
I have already include the  Google APIs client library for PHP.
I am unable to use set and render function which are shown in the code

```
this is My index.html


    <!-- The top of file index.html -->
    <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <head>
    <!-- BEGIN Pre-requisites -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     (function () {
      var po = document.createElement('script');
      po.type = 'text/javascript';
      po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=start';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
  </script>
  <!-- END Pre-requisites -->
</head>
<!-- ... -->
</html>

<!-- Add where you want your sign-in button to render -->
<div id="signinButton">
  <span class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

    <!-- Last part of BODY element in file index.html -->
   <script type="text/javascript">

      function signInCallback(authResult) {
      if (authResult['code']) {

      // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
     $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

     // Send the code to the server
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'plus.php?storeToken',
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(result) {
        // Handle or verify the server response if necessary.

        // Prints the list of people that the user has allowed the app to know
        // to the console.
        console.log(result);
        if (result['profile'] && result['people']){
          $('#results').html('Hello ' + result['profile']['displayName'] + '. You successfully made a server side call to people.get and people.list');
        } else {
          $('#results').html('Failed to make a server-side call. Check your configuration and console.');
        }
      },
      processData: false,
      data: authResult['code']
    });
    }  
     else if (authResult['error']) {
      // There was an error.
      // Possible error codes:
      //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
      //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatially log in the user
      // console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting???

Comment: hey the problem is in the code.php i am using set and render function which are the defined in Google APIs client library.and i navigate the whole of the library.there are lot of different set and render function. so I do not know which one i have to use

Comment: hey index.html is not given the error. The main problem is set and render functions are defined in Google APIs client library and these two functions are defined in different-2 classes.So i have to make the object of the class.But i do not know for Which class i have to make the instance.Because these two functions are defined in several files in the Google APIs client library

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: app in E:\wamp\www\google+\code.php on line 11                                                               Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\google+\code.php on line 11

Comment: Anybody help me out. I am looking for the help.There are lot of set and render function in the whole Google APIs client library. which set and render Function I have to use.Plz help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the documentation providing you incomplete code snippets (I've opened a bug about that). That particular sample relies on Symfony, which is what you're encountering with the missing variable/method.

The [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php) provides the full instructions to get this particular sample set up. You can also [get the full source code from Github](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php).

You don't have to use Symfony of course but if you choose to go with native PHP methods, you'd need to update the references to $request, $app, and other Symfony methods that the sample uses.

Comment: Hey i have already seen the Github code.What i am trying to do ,is I have to include the Google+ sign-up button in my application and the authentication should be done by the server and i have to collect the user info also

Comment: The quickstart code should handle that for you. The /connect method starting on line 82 contains the logic to exchange the one-time-code for both a refresh token and access token that your server can hold on to.

Server side tokens with the Google+ Sign-In button is a hybrid flow between the client and server. Its not completely on the server-side. If you want a completely server-side flow, you'd need to go with native OAuth using the Google PHP client library and using the access type of offline with a redirect URI. The Google+ Sign-In button always uses a redirect_uri of postmessage.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

SignIn/SignUp links:

> 1. http://www.w3resource.com/API/google-plus/tutorial.php
> 2. http://rscavilla.blogspot.in/2011/06/using-oauth-20-with-php-to-authenticate.html

To get user info:

> Look at [this code](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/userinfo/index.php) to get the user-info from the Google+ API.

The problem is you don't have a `$app` object on your application that can call the `set` method when your app is trying to set the state in the session.

That said, the documentation on the google side tells the user who reads the document to ensure that state value is stored in their application session and how the other required value for the google_auth API should be stored.

**Tutorial:**

Take a look into [this link](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/login-with-google-account-oauth.html) for more detailed tutorial on how to configure and use Google OAuth API.

Comment: hey Thanks for your link. Is this server side sign-up for google+

Comment: hey RakeshS I am looking for google+ server-side sign-up for my application

Comment: Anybody help me out. I am looking for the help

Comment: The link provided by you is not much beneficial for me. i am looking for https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow. type sign up

Comment: hey thanks for the help but I am looking for the sign-up with google+ button.just like in https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

Comment: I thought I had already given explanation in the above answer with an update. Use the user-info API to retrieve the user data from google account and store them to your tables.

Comment: I have used the user-info API but the problem is, I want to include the Google+ sign-up button in my application instead of a simple link.

Comment: Is this [what you are looking](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#step_3_adding_a_sign-in_button_to_your_page) for??

Comment: I am looking for google+ server side sign-up with the google+ button and after the sign-up i want to store the data in the db. I have to do all of these things in Yii framework

Comment: Hey RakeshS I am looking for server side flow

Comment: Visit any freelance website and pay them to code, you want the whole code. If yes, then this is not the place, it is only for those who are stuck on a problem and have no where else to go to complete the solution.

Comment: hey i am not looking for the whole of the code. I am looking for which library file i should use because there are lot of files in the Google APIs client library and how can i customize the google+ button