# Stopping Duplicate Submission or Double Click Submission

Tags: php, forms, laravel, form-submit

First, I realize that there are other questions asked that are similar to this one, but they do not contain any definitive solutions to my problem.

When a customer submits an order, I need to be able to properly prevent my processing script from running more than once for that particular order.

`/payment` - the customer fills in all of their details and submits the order

`/process_order` - collects all of the data and processes the order.

What is happening is that my orders are being processed partially and then processed again fully ... and I can only assume that this is because customers are either double-clicking on the submit button, or are clicking the submit button a second time because the process hasn't completed and the browser hasn't redirected to the 'thank you' page yet...

I could just use jQuery to disable the button upon the first click event, but I'd also like to know what I could do on the server side of things to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to create, essentially, a nonce token for your form and store it in the session when showing the form.

```
$_SESSION['formNonce'] = md5( time() . uniquid() );
```

When generating the form, add it as a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formNonce" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['formNonce']); ?>">
```

And then when processing it, the first thing you do is validate the nonce is in the session and then remove it. In this way, a second submission won't pass the validation because the nonce token has been removed.

There would be some tweaking and error checking to all of this, but coupled with the javascript button disabling could be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use "anti-forgery tockens" approach. Once user does visit a page, there is a tocken assigned. First attempts to submit the page will remove the tocken from valid list so further attempts would fail.

Comment: Can you produce an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276513/how-to-create-an-anti-request-forgery-state-token-in-google-server-side-sign-up

Comment: I've seen this answer several times and it doesn't tell me anything other than general statements. I need examples that mean something...