# Where do I generate a Google+ signin API anti-request forgery state token?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm using this guide: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow.
Step 2 says "Create an anti-request forgery state token" and gives this example code:

```
// Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
// Store it in the session for later validation.
  $state = md5(rand());
  $app['session']->set('state', $state);
  // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
  // serving it.
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
      'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
      'STATE' => $state,
      'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
  ));
```

Where do I put this code? I have no clue. I tried putting it before the confirmation on the server in step 7, but that seems wrong. I get an internal server error. I tried putting it before the HTML on the page where the signin button is located. The page won't even load.

Google's tutorials seem really bad. In one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276513/how-to-create-an-anti-request-forgery-state-token-in-google-server-side-sign-up) it says that the code in the tutorial is incomplete. Is this true? Anyone know any better up-to-date guides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be done server-side as one of the things that is done when returning the page. If you're using an MVC framework, and this code assumes you are or at least are using a template engine, this should be part of the controller that handles sending the page back.

Comment: Does it have to be rendered with HTML server side for it to be safe? What if my page is static HTML with ajax (Web 2.0), can I create a web service that returns the state token and call it with Ajax without compromising security?

Comment: @marquez -short answer: yes, you can do that with the google+ sign-in. Read the docs at the url in the question, and if you have a specific question or concern, feel free to ask as a new SO question.